# How to create an object with a method in Typescript

Tags: typescript, game-development

I feel like my problem is niche, but here goes.  I want my sprite object to contain all the sprites I will need along with their corresponding information.  I have achieved this in Javascript and am trying to learn Typescript.  So there is the Javascript code in question:

```
const sprites = {
    addImage(image, width, height)
    {
        this[image] = new Image();
        this[image].src = "./assets/images/" + image + ".png";
        this[image].width = width;
        this[image].height = height;
    }
};
```

I have tried so far to do the Typescript equivalent and made it to here:

```
let sprites: {
    name: string,
    src: HTMLImageElement,
    width: number,
    height: number
    addSprite: (image: string, width: number, height: number) => {
        this[image] = new Image();
    }
}
```

this[image] is already giving me an issue and I am unsure if there would be a way to nest my objects the way I am looking to do.

For additional info, I then assign my objects an image name so they can then be called as follows to display (following is called in a forEach, hence element):
`gameCanvas.drawImage(sprites[element.image], element.x, element.y, sprites[element.image].width, sprites[element.image].height);`
which is why I ideally would like to keep the format sprite[imageName]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: is that a typo or not `this[image]=`? it should be `this['image']=` or `this.image`

Comment: image is the variable that contains the name of the image I want it to apply, so if the variable was "grass" with a width of 64px, you would then be able to fetch that information by typing sprites.grass.width, but here "grass" is stored in image, so it would be sprites[image].width.  I don't know if that makes it any clearer :S

Edited to add: The function that I am trying to write is basically the declaration function to then create all my image info under the object name sprite.

Comment: Do you want it to work precisely in the previous example in a type-safe manner?

Comment: Pretty much, yes, so I can call sprite[insert variable with image name here] and get the data included within.  If I have to create an object for each of these, it will make it considerably harder for me to automate the image display of multiple items.

Comment: And if the value passed for `image` is `"addImage"` (or is it `"addSprite"`? wish this were a [mre]) then you'll be overwriting the method.  TS doesn't want to let me do that, so maybe you could give some kind of prefix to image keys?  Like `img:`, and that could give you [this approach (it's an IDE link)](https://tsplay.dev/wEYzZw).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Apologies, my first question here.  Quick usage example:
`sprites.addImage("ground1", 64, 64);
sprites.addImage("water1", 64, 64);
sprites.addImage("mossmiddle", 64, 64);

tiles = ["water1", "water1", "ground1", "mossmiddle", "ground1"];
tiles.forEach(element, index) => {
gameCanvas.drawImage(sprites[element], index * 64, 500, sprites[element].width, sprites[element].height);
}`

Comment: Was that in reply to my comment? If so, can you explain how?  In any case, if that code is needed for a [mre] you should [edit] it into the question and not just leave it in a comment.